# Get Height Of Multi Level Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a multilevel drop-down menu. There is a problem when I try to get
height of the element at level 2, but level 1 is working correctly. Why?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uw/)**

```js
alert($('ul.sub-1').outerHeight()); // --> 240
alert($('ul.sub-2').outerHeight()); // --> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use visibility instead of display.  see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/eY8uw/1/)

```
ul.sub-menu {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;

li:hover > .sub-menu {
visibility: visible; 
}
```